# How to select all objects with same normals direction in 3Ds Max using maxscript or pymxs?

Tags: python, 3dsmax, normals, maxscript

[image]Need help to write the code on Python (pymxs) or Maxscript which can allow to select all objects with same normals direction in 3Ds Msx.

I have this base function, but can't achieve needed result.

```
import pymxs
def select_same_normal_objects(normal_dir):
    selection_set = []
    geometry_objects = list(rt.execute('''for o in geometry where (isKindOf o GeometryClass and canConvertTo o Editable_Mesh) collect o'''))
    for obj in geometry_objects:
        if obj.getNormal() == normal_dir:
            selection_set.append(obj)
    return selection_set
```

Comment: What do you mean with "object's normal direction"? There is no `getNormal()` method for objects, only for vertices and faces.

Comment: I mean faces normal direction

Comment: An object will most likely have a lot of faces with different face normals. You need to elaborate more about this line `if obj.getNormal() == normal_dir:` Do you want all faces with that direction from an object or some average normal describing the objects orientation?

Comment: Yes, I need to get those objects whose face normals look in one direction, along the Z-axis for example

Comment: Please add an image/screenshot to your question to clarify how your objects look like. This makes not really sense for closed (waterproof) geometry.

Comment: I added screenshot. It's not a single object

Comment: Ok, and are all these objects (for example the white ones) *closed* geometry?

Comment: Yes, it is closed

Comment: Please understand that it is not easy to define how an object is supposed to "look" into a specific direction without further conventions. A closed geometry will have face normals looking wildly in all directions. You could instead take the z-axis of the local tranformation or from the global transformation or another axis or..., thats up to your definition of "object's normal direction". But this setup must be used then for all geometries consistently (at the time of modeling) or your function (using this convention) will not work reliably.

Comment: Imagine two boxes, one is rotated 90 degrees: both boxes will have face normals in all six directions. Where is "object direction"?

Comment: in fact, I need exactly the direction of faces. Because in fact, I have to select all faces of objects whose normals look in one direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, specifically this statement

> I have to select all faces of objects whose normals look in one direction

you could do something like:

```
def select_same_normal_objects(normal_dir):
    selection_dict = dict()
    geometry_objects = list(rt.execute("for o in geometry where (isKindOf o GeometryClass and canConvertTo o Editable_Mesh) collect o"))
    
    for obj in geometry_objects:
        
        # get a "get face normal" function for the obj type
        getFaceNormal = None
        if str(rt.classof(obj)) == 'Editable_Poly':
            getFaceNormal = pymxs.runtime.polyop.getFaceNormal
        elif str(rt.classof(obj)) == 'Editable_mesh':
            getFaceNormal = pymxs.runtime.getFaceNormal
        else:
            pass  # implement getFaceNormal() for other object types

        if getFaceNormal:
            for i in range(pymxs.runtime.getNumFaces(obj)):
                # careful that maxscript has one-based indices
                normal = getFaceNormal(obj, i+1)
                if normal == normal_dir:
                    if obj not in selection_dict:
                        selection_dict[obj] = [i+1]
                    else:
                        selection_dict[obj].append(i+1)
    return selection_dict
```

This returns you a dictionary with all found faces per object

```
{
   obj1: [1,2,4,...],
   obj2: [5,11,...],
   ...
}
```